# TaskCanceledException in ShutDownListener

Tags: c#, .net

We are currently seeing a lot of `TaskCanceledException` thrown off `MS.Internal.ShutDownListener.HandleShutDown`. This started in the middle of may and could be related to some Update to .Net or Windows 10. We see this in old (~2 years old) and new versions of our software and it just started across all versions. We target .Net 4 Client profile with older version and .Net 4.5.1 with newer versions.

The full stack trace is:

> TaskCanceledException at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherOperation
>   operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback,
>   DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
>   TimeSpan timeout) at MS.Internal.WeakEventTable.OnShutDown() at
>   MS.Internal.ShutDownListener.HandleShutDown(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e)

The question is: what is causing this?

Right now, we are looking for approaches to find the root cause and eventually a fix for this. Of course, we can simply catch it in the end, but that's not an actual solution. Any hints in the direction are welcome. We'd like to update this question as we gain more insight to be able to provide information for people coming across this later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been seeing this too. There's an arbitrary 300ms time limit during shutdown if you look at the source ~278:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/MS/Internal/WeakEventTable.cs

```
try
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)OnShutDown, DispatcherPriority.Send, CancellationToken.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
    succeeded = true;
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
}
```

It raises even though the internal collections in the WeakEventTable are all emptied out.

[image]

Whoever wrote it didn't anticipate the runtime throwing `TaskCanceledException` since probably it never used to. The workaround I'm taking is to remove all use of WeakEventManager.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing towards a direction! Unfortunately, we use Prism which relies on the WeakEventManager, but I can further investigate in this direction about what we can do here. The main problem at the moment is, that we can't really reproduce this on our machines, we only hear it from our users.

Comment: For now, we use this insight to filter out this exception with WeakEventManager in the stack trace and will try to reach out towards Microsoft to finally resolve the root cause. Thanks for pointing us in the right direction!

Comment: Did you get a chance to reach out to mocrosoft on this? Please share if any reference of this incident.

Comment: If (hopefully) have now found the right place to submit this issue here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/284294/taskcanceledexception-during-application-shutdown.html
I will also keep an eye on that and will try to update more helpful information here once they are available.

Comment: There was a link to this document:
In the VS community, a link to this document was posted, which probably explains it a bit:
https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/Documentation/compatibility/wpf-AppDomain-shutdown-handling-may-now-call-Dispatcher.Invoke-in-cleanup-of-WeakEvents.md
It talks about applications not handling the Dispatcher lifetime properly, but I can't find any documentation on how it is intended to be handled and if this has changed with .Net 4.7.2 or not.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a workaround, at least for .NET Framework 4.7.2

https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/Documentation/compatibility/wpf-AppDomain-shutdown-handling-may-now-call-Dispatcher.Invoke-in-cleanup-of-WeakEvents.md

## Change Description

In .NET Framework 4.7.1 and earlier versions, WPF potentially creates a `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher` on the .NET finalizer thread during `AppDomain` shutdown. This was fixed in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions by making the cleanup of weak events thread-aware. Due to this, WPF may call `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke` to complete the cleanup process.

In certain applications, this change in finalizer timing can potentially cause exceptions during `AppDomain` or process shutdown. This is generally seen in applications that do not correctly shut down dispatchers running on worker threads prior to process or `AppDomain` shutdown. Such applications should take care to properly manage the lifetime of dispatchers.

## Recommended Action

In .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions, developers can disable this fix in order to help alleviate (but not eliminate) timing issues that may occur due to the cleanup change.

To disable the change in cleanup, use the following `AppContext` flag.

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.MS.Internal.DoNotInvokeInWeakEventTableShutdownListener=true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```